# JS object properties undefined after I've used JSON.parse(), and properties have no invalid characters?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

Here is my code from Google Scripts:

```
var request = 
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.example.com/v2/directory/myuserid.json?
key=myapikey');
Logger.log(request); // see below
JSON.parse(request);
Logger.log(request); // see below
Logger.log(request["meta"]); // undefined
var meta = "meta";
Logger.log(request.meta); // undefined
```

When I log request before and after it's parsed, I get the following:

```
{"meta":{"requests":67,"timestamp":1497800064,"status":200,"message":"Request successful","method_id":1201,"method":{}},"data":{"full_name":"my name","given_name":"given name","last_name":"last name","user_id":"user id","department":"eng","common_names":["first last"],"email_addresses":[],"offices":[],"telephone_numbers":[],"homepage":""}}
```

This only seems to be happening with this particular API that I am using.

Comment: Have you `console.log(obj)` to see if it actually contains what you think it contains right before you are trying to use `obj["meta"]`? And show the actual code that you are using to retrieve the JSON and then use it. Since you are fetching JSON you might be trying to access `obj` before it has been populated by the async request

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yes I have done this, that's how I knew what object I was getting back. The cut and paste from the console log is what you see. Will update with entire code

Comment: from your console log, you do `JSON.parse(request)`, and then do `Logger.log(request["meta"])`. `JSON.parse` does not modify `request`, it returns the parsed object, you need something like `obj = JSON.parse(request)`

Comment: Also you seem to be under the impression that doing `meta="meta"` and then doing `request.meta` will try to use the variable meta as a way of naming a property, it wont you would use the meta variable like so `request[meta]` (notice no quotes)

Comment: @PatrickEvans Ah, issue solved! I thought that JSON.parse() modified request. Thank you so much sir. I'm not sure about your other point though, but I'm sure you're right